# What is GUI toolkit better architecture?

Tags: user-interface, x11

I am working on a lightweight GUI toolkit. It is designed to be easy portable in X11 (xlib), Win32 and possibly other systems with very rudimental GUI support.

As far as I know, there are mainly two possible architectures:

1. To use the OS provided windows services - X11 in Linux and normal windows in Win32. In this approach, every control is the same window object as its parent. It receives events from the OS and processes them, has its own painting surface, etc.
2. To use the OS provided windows only for the top level windows - main application window, dialog boxes, etc. All child windows are simply painted on the surface of its parent window. In this case, the toolkit has to manage parent-child relations, the events are only received by the main window and has to be dispatched to the controls.

What variant use the widespread GUI toolkits? Qt? wxWidgets? FLTK? Others? Why they choose this approach?

How are both variants related to the size and speed of the result GUI toolkit?

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: The reason to prefer the first is it's *extremely* difficult to get all the nuances of native controls right. For example, glow effects on hover. Even Qt, with all the development effort that has gone into it, doesn't get those right on either Windows or OS X (it uses the second approach). So no, the first is far from obsolete. But the second does have some advantages, like giving you ultimate power over how the controls are drawn.

Comment: The question has been minimized again in hope to be reopen. :)

Comment: There's a third possible architecture; Ignore the OS as much as possible and create all your own GUI components. Although you could hardly call this approach lightweight.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc It is the second actually. In the modern OSes the toolkit has to get access to some drawing surface, so it has to use the OS provided windows at least for the top level windows. (Of course I am talking about GUI OSes. On DOS or Linux without X there is no choice at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make a comment yet but I strongly advice against going into X right now, in more or less two years Wayland (or Mir, maybe) will be the main rendering manager for Linux.

And I think the main problem with the first approach is that :

- You have to get a perfect knowledge of the both systems (X & Win32 (and why not Cocoa for OS X?))
- If X changes a little implementation detail somewhere you will have to change your code to take this into account, while if you only use the top level stuff, it is less likely to change.
- There might be tons and tons of code duplications (ex. : handling checkboxes for Win32 and X...)

Comment: I, on the contrary, disagree. X Window System will live for a looooong time after Wayland goes mainstream, because there are so many unix flavors, commercial ones, that will probably never go Wayland way. If he does not want to support UNIX systems, then perhaps Wayland is a good way to go, otherwise he will have to support X - it will be a must.

Comment: Additionally, there are projects like EGLX which can be used to run X applications on Wayland.